# How can I get all the link titles?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get the list of all the names from [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions) (the champion link titles in the table) but I'm having no success.. Can anyone direct me what's wrong with this code please?

Thank you!

```
var url = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);            

foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[3]/tr"))
{
    HtmlNode item = table.SelectSingleNode("//a");
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttributeValue("title", false));
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Alright, I got it to work just fine with this code:

```
var url = "http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);            

foreach (HtmlNode item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[3]/tr/td/span/a"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["title"].Value);
}

return true;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the xpath this way

```
foreach (HtmlNode linkItem in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[3]/tr//a"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(linkItem.Attributes["title"].Value());
    Console.WriteLine(linkItem.Attributes["alt"].Value());
}
```

Comment: that throws a bunch of FormatExceptions >.>

Comment: Now it works fine, it was the before-edit code. Well, not really fine, it prints each name twice for some reason beyond me >.>

Comment: @argoneus its not beyond you, its because the alt text is the exact same text as the title text, hence each is printed twice. for example go to that page and hover over the top name, that text in the box while your hovering is the alt text, notice how its the same for every name. its a compatibility thing with screen readers and the likes of other accessibility software

Comment: But I only got the 'title' attribute in my code and it still prints it twice. I think it's because the link is there twice, not sure how to fix that..

Comment: @argoneus I gave you the choice to get the text either by attribute title or alt you can choose the one you want

Comment: @argoneus you page is blocked for me hecne i cannot see the html but are you sure that their are no more than one link in each tr because the xpath syntax //a will get all link from that tr

Comment: yes, there are two links under each, one for image and one for the name

Comment: if you want the first then /a[1] else the second  use this way /a[2] in your Xpath

Answer (score 1):

I knocked up a quick and dirty example, tested and works flawlessly, you'll want to format the result a bit though:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      List<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> test = GetInnerTest();

      foreach (var node in test)
      {
            Response.Write("Result: " + node.InnerHtml.ToString());
      }

}

public List<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> GetInnerTest()
{
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

     doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
     doc.Load(requestData("http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_champions"));

     var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("character_icon")).ToList();

     return node;
}


public StreamReader requestData(string url)
{
       HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
       HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

       StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());

       return sr;
}
```

You'll need to download [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and include a reference for it to work.

Comment: I understand how that works, except, a question: I don't quite get the syntax of 'Where' (in GetInnerTest()), is it basically a lambda?